# Fancybox not loading youtube video

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

I am using fancybox for my image gallery and I created a duplicate page but instead of image files I've added the youTube link to show videos, but the videos do not load when I click on the thumbnail.

js :

```
$("a.fancy").fancybox({
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.7,
    'overlayColor' : '#000',
    'titlePosition' : 'over',
    'onComplete' : function () {
        $("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function () {
            $("#fancybox-title").show();
        }, function () {
            $("#fancybox-title").hide();
        });
    }
});
```

html :

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7h4o08e-uLw" class="fancy" rel="macro-group">youtube</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stPqD4KOT9c&noredirect=1" class="fancy" rel="macro-group">
```

http://jfastudio.com/video-gallery.html

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is :

1. Convert all youtube's `URL`s to this format :

   ```
   https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video id}?{first trailing parameter}&{second trailing parameter}
   ```
2. Add the *class* `iframe` to your existing anchor *class* like

   ```
   <a href="{URL}" class="fancy iframe" ...
   ```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3n4yhu1u/1/)**

**Note** : this is for fancybox v1.3.4.

---

**EDIT**

If using fancybox v2.x, then add *class* `fancybox.iframe` instead.

Yes :

```
class="fancy fancybox.iframe"
```

... would be correct.